# How to interactively get data from php script using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have this php script:

```
<?php
$arr = array(array("a","b"),array("c","d"));
qq($arr);
function qq($arr){
foreach($arr as $ar => $r){
//getting some work done
//sending the array $r (or values)to javascript
}
}
?>
```

Is it possible to get the value of 0 array using javascript before array 1.

what i get so far is this js from stackoverflow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function q(){

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.0.1/q.php");
xmlhttp.send(null);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction;

function callbackFunction(){
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
xml = xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("q").value = xml;
}}}
</script>
```

but it's not doing what i want(i think i'm missing something).

my html:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="q();" />
<div id="q"></div>
<div id="q1"></div>
```

Is it possible to put array 0 value in div(id=q) and when array 1 is ready put it's value in div(id=q1)

Comment: what value you are getting in xml ?

Comment: I'm getting a string of numbers that i need to process but it's taking too much time, so i'm thinking of a way to print one set of array before 2nd array is created. (Oh that xml variable is not related to XML)

Comment: Is it not possible to send two requests? Either simultaneously or trigger the second on completion of the first?

Comment: That requires me to create lots of functions for similar tasks, but i think it can be done via long polling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "normal" HTTP Requests via XMLHttpRequest() do not allow such behaviour in a single request.

You have the following options instead:

### [Server Send Events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events)

#### upside

- They are incredibly easy to build. Nothing really special is needed on the server. Just google for server sent events and you'll find some examples on how they work.
- They go through proxys and firewalls just as well as any other http request, because it is a normal http request.

#### downside

- Does not run on Internet Explorer (?)
- May fail to update in realtime if a proxy somewhere buffers too much. However in this case it still works, it just misses the realtime communication

### [Websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

#### upside

Works in all recent browsers. Enables you to do full duplex communication and gets everything right that you need.

#### downside

- May or may not work through proxies depending on their configuration.
- Special extensions are needed on the server

### [(Long-) polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling)

#### upside

- Best compatibility (works even in older browsers, no issues with proxies or firewalls)

#### downside

- Creates lots of overhead because it does create for each message a new http connection
- You need to store intermediate results somewhere because the poll requests come in different threads to your application than your code generation mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

can you try with

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
  xml = xmlhttp.responseText;
  document.getElementById('q').innerHTML=xml;
}}}
```

Comment: Sorry, but actually i'm getting a response but not what i want.I want to get values from a php script while php script is running.